# Google Chart Tools not working in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart Tools to display a chart. The chart is not working, and `WebView` is not loading.  I used the URL https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chart Tools use SVG to render the charts, and while WebKit does have support for SVG, it does use a lot of memory, so it is not compiled in to earlier versions for Android. Android 4.0 should be supported (heavy on the should, I haven't tested it).

If you need support for earlier models, you may be able to use [Google Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/), an image-only version that Google has deprecated.